# Как вывести список из диапазона значений в CSV

Tags: python, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести значения из диапазона чисел?
Входной файл.csv следующего вида:

| prefix | Value_2 | Value_3 | quantity | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4562000 | 4563999 | 2000 | name_1 |
| 123 | 4567800 | 4567839 | 40 | name_2 |

Необходимо из него (методом регулярного выражения d+) импортировать данные c отсечкой разряда чисел, входящих в данный диапазон, записав это в файл2.csv следующего вида:

| Value | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1234562 | name_1 |
| 1234563 | name_1 |
| 123456780 | name_2 |
| 123456781 | name_2 |
| 123456782 | name_2 |
| 123456783 | name_2 |

Comment: 1) Я не понял как из первой таблички получилась вторая. Объясните принцип. 2) В чём у вас собственно сложность? А так то с табличками в `csv` проще всего через библиотеку `Pandas` работать.

Comment: 1) Из первого столбца первой таблицы берётся префикс без изменений, к нему добавляется из 2-го и 3-го столбцов номерная емкость за исключением тех разрядов чисел (в конце), которые входят в эту емкость, т.е.: 1234562\d+ (тысяча номеров);1234563\d+ (вторая тысяча номеров), и т.д. 2) каким методом можно вывести такой список, и есть ли необходимость задействовать в этом столбец с данными 'quantity'?

Comment: Ну, похоже хитростей тут никаких не придумать - вот берёте и делаете как написано. Циклом от первого получившегося стыковкой числа до второго получившегося числа. quantity вроде бы не нужно, достаточно тех двух чисел, просто range от одного числа, до второго + 1.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.